Movie with infectious disease indicated via nosebleed from the 00s (probably)
Things I vaguely remember:

Possibly terrorist and possibly started on a plane (but I might be mixing with MI2 here)
Highly infectious
The infection has a symbol?
Any character with a nosebleed is highly infectious and will die soon
There is an antidote (but only in the nick of time, of course)
English
Probably A-lister type people, maybe.
Fairly sure the main protagonists are an adult male and female
Action movie!

Scenes I can remember:

There is a dinner in a restaurant where we see on a napkin that someone we are sympathetic to has developed a nose-bleed which means they are infected.
Very close to the end the lead bloke finds out he is infected and runs away. The other protagonists manage to track him down and are hovering above in a helicopter, in order to communicate that he is infectious he uses fuel to draw a symbol on the ground and sets it alight. He is rescued and put in isolation and, of course, makes it.

That is all I remember! Not much to go on, I know.

Are you thinking of Outbreak?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outbreak_(film)

It could be, there don't seem to be any mention of nosebleeds which perhaps were not as important as I remember. I can't find any useful clips so I'll have to get hold of a copy of the movie to find the specific scenes I'm after. But the lead roles seem to fit, and there's certainly mention of helicopters!

Outbreak was filmed here in Humboldt County, California. The helicopter chase is along the Eel River as it winds its way through redwoods and Douglas Fir forests, and the small, quaint "Victorian Village" of Ferndale was  used as the center of the outbreak, with lots of locals participating as extras. I've seen the movie at least three times, and the only thing I don't recall is the "fire ring" you're describing; however, that could just be my memory as I haven't rented the movie in probably a decade. It was an exciting experience for those of us who live here in the Eureka/Arcata area.

Oh wow! That's pretty awesome, we don't have anything as exciting as that here!

One movie where nosebleeds indicated infection was the remake of Day of the Dead, but it doesn't sound like you're looking for a zombie movie.

Any chance its The Crazies?

Apart from the ending you describe, and a couple of other, more minor details, it sounds a lot like Twelve Monkeys
